# Which adusers in a specific department are managers of Exchange Distribution groups?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server

I have listed users in our AD with this:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties department |
    Where-Object {$_.department -Like "F0*"} |
    Select sAMAccountName, department
```

It outputs all users of interest.

Now I wanna go through these users and find all of them that are managers of one or several Exchange distribution Groups. And have an output with username and name of distribution Group(s) , is this possible?

Comment: `Get-DistributionGroup` has a `managedby` variable that stores the managers of each group. This should help you create a loop to achieve your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

As Paxz already commented, you should go 'the other way' on this. If you want to get names and departments of managers of distribution groups, start with getting those first.

Something like this would probably do it:

```
# get the distribution groups where the ManagedBy property is set
Get-DistributionGroup | Where-Object { $_.ManagedBy } | ForEach-Object {
    # then go through all possible listed managers and get their DisplayName and Department
    foreach ($id in $_.ManagedBy) {
        try {
            # use '-ErrorAction Stop' to make sure the catch block is entered upon failure
            $manager = Get-AdUser -Identity $id -Properties DisplayName, Department -ErrorAction Stop
            $mgrName = $manager.DisplayName
            $mgrDept = $manager.Department
        }
        catch {
            # output failed result(s)
            $mgrName = 'Obsolete user'
            $mgrDept = 'Unknown'
        }
        # output the result(s) as PSObjects
        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
            'Distribution Group' = $_.Name
            'Manager'            = $mgrName
            'Department'         = $mgrDept
        }
    }
}
```

If you would like to store the results in a csv file, you can extend the script to something like this:

```
$fileName = '<Enter the full path and filename here for the output csv file>'
# collect all results in an array
$results = @()
Get-DistributionGroup | Where-Object { $_.ManagedBy } | ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($id in $_.ManagedBy) {
        try {
            # use '-ErrorAction Stop' to make sure the catch block is entered upon failure
            $manager = Get-AdUser -Identity $id -Properties DisplayName, Department -ErrorAction Stop
            $mgrName = $manager.DisplayName
            $mgrDept = $manager.Department
        }
        catch {
            # output failed result(s)
            $mgrName = 'Obsolete user'
            $mgrDept = 'Unknown'
        }
        $results += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
            'Distribution Group' = $_.Name
            'Manager'            = $mgrName
            'Department'         = $mgrDept
    }
}

$results | Export-Csv -Path $fileName -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Comment: thank you very much, there seems to be a problem though with Get-Aduser, it stops when finding an obsolete object. (Get-AdUser : Cannot find an object with identity:) , I have tried -Erroraction SilentlyContinue but it doesnt work, trying to get Try/Catch but cant figure out how to write it in.

Comment: I have edited my answer to capture obsolete users by adding `try{}..catch{}` blocks